# How to enable vertical scrolling on some levels in multi-level fly-out menu

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a multi-level flyout menu that will later be a part of daterange picker to be able to select a period of time. Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6t72hd4x/1/

I tried to enable `overflow-y: auto;` in `.inner-list` class, to handle vertical overflow of the year list (https://jsfiddle.net/6t72hd4x) 
This however messed with horizontal overflow - inner lists are no longer visible. Adding `overflow-x: visible` didn't help.

Is there a way to make both inner menus and vertical scrolling possible at the same time?

Just want to mention that I am a backend dev with little frontend experience, so my approach here might be completele wrong.

Comment: you can't set `overflow-x: visible;` and have `overflow-y: scroll` because when you set `overflow-y:` to `scroll;` `overflow-x` will default back to auto, that's just how browser computes overflows, a solution would be to have the Quarters list as sibling of the parent year, and use `year+quarter` for displaying it on hover.

Info about overflows: https://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however the solution you have suggested does not really solve this, because even if I had list of quarters as a sibling to a year, the overflow-y is set on their common parent div, so it still can't fly out to the side. Perpahps you meant to set list of quarters a a sibling to the list of years. I know this would work, but it would be more awkward (not impossible, i know) to get which year the quarter/month belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use javascript to decide "which year the qarter/month belongs to", a quick fix would be to position the child elements of the overflowed container relative to the viewport (`position:fixed;`): https://jsfiddle.net/69yLp2fa/16/

---

**Edit**

Or with absolute positioning, but the rule is not to use `overflow` and `position` on the same container. Create another container for the overflown element and move positioning there, so that the absolute positioned child will not be placed relative to the overflow ancestor:
https://jsfiddle.net/hg8rbksy/2/

Comment: True, but I indeed need to know which year the inner period belongs to. My goal here is that click event on either of these would result in start and end date for selected period. I believe it would still be possible with javascript even if the inner list is not descendant of specific year, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: After some tries I've managed to find a way without fixed position and edited my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is quite good. I have accepted your answer since this is what I was looking for. However, now that the inner lists are anchored to the top you can't hover-through to inner list from elements that are down of inner-list height. Do you think the top-property of positionedchild can be calculated from its parent's position?

Comment: Indeed that doesn't look good, one way to fix is to replace 'top' property of positionedchild with 'margin-top:-20px;' (or the height of the span element once you know it): https://jsfiddle.net/k72n6cdw/9/

Comment: I have tried this as well, but once you scroll down a bit in year list, this no longer works well - inner list is relative to its parent's position as if there were no overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/x8mkant0/1/

Comment: Fixed with a bit of jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/z0mLsxgp/39/
Credit goes to: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/